# How to add 2 time values which are in different formats

Tags: excel, time, format, addition

I want to add D6 and D16 which are:

[image]

[image]

But I cant add them since they are not in same format. I want to get 22458:10 in [h]:mm format as a result. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first snapshot I see that the formula bar shows a time, while on the second it shows the same text as in the cell. That means that on the first table you have numbers formatted as custom time, on the second you have just a text.

You need a formula that converts that text into a number, then you can do the math using that number.

The formula is this:

```
=(VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1)-1))*60+VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,2)))/24/60
```

I noticed that Excel can add up two numbers and show `30000:00`, but can't recognize it as a time if you type it. After calculating the value you can copy and paste it as a value, so the value replaces the text.

EDIT 1:

When the user enters a text in a cell, Excel analyzes the text and tries to guess the user intention using a logic similar to this:

- If all the characters are numbers then it's a number
- If the first character is an `=` then it's a formula
- If there are 2 or 3 groups of numbers separated by `-` or by `/` then it's a date
- If there are 2 or 3 groups of numbers separated by `:` then it's a time

This is usually done using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to check whether the text matches the pattern that defines a number, a formula, a date or a time.

For example it looks like Excel uses a regular expression that matches 1 to 4 numbers followed by a colon followed by 1 to 2 numbers. A Python regular expression to match this would be `{1,4}\d\:{1,2}\d`.

When Excel guesses that you want to enter a time because what you typed looks like a time, it calculates the fraction of day you entered, sets the cell value to the calculated number and sets the cell format to time, so you see what you typed. For example if you type `6:00`, Excel calculates 6 hours from midnight, which is one quarter of a day, so it sets the cell value to 0.25 and the format to time. If you then change the cell format to number you will see that there is the 0.25.

Storing times as numbers allows to use them in formulas, which would be impossible if they were stored as texts.

Your problem is that one Excel guy decided that when the users types `1234:12` then the user meant to write a time, but when the user types `12345:12` then the user meant to write just a text.

So it's up to you to convert that text into a number, and then to set the time format to the cell.

You can do it with the formula above (which is long, but simple), or with a VBA macro that is fired every time a cell is modified, and does it when the text matches `12345:12`, or with a macro that checks all the cells in a file, or with a macro that does it when you import a file, or... you got the point.

EDIT 2:

Here is a function that converts all the texts with 5 or 6 numbers followed by a colon followed by 2 numbers:

```
Sub ConvertTimesWith5Or6Digits()
  Dim C As Range, Text As String, Hours As String, Minutes As String, PosColon As Integer
  For Each C In Sheet1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Cells
    If C.Value2 Like "#####:##" Or C.Value2 Like "######:##" Then
      Text = C.Value2
      PosColon = InStr(Text, ":")
      Hours = Left(Text, PosColon - 1)
      Minutes = Mid(Text, PosColon + 1)
      C.Formula = (Val(Hours) * 60 + Val(Minutes)) / 24 / 60
      C.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm"
    End If
  Next C
End Sub
```

Comment: +1.....Excel doesn't recognise input time values above 9999:59. Note you don't need the VALUE functions - this should work `=(LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1)-1)+MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,2)/60)/24`

Comment: @barryhoudini Right. I put the `Value()` because in VBA both the `+` and the `&` operators with strings returns a string. In Excel the `+` only works with numbers, so it takes care of converting the strings into numbers.

Comment: wow, i thought we could just do some formatting and get a result. that is hell of a long formula. is it the only way?

Comment: Long formulas don't hurt :) The point is that the problem is that the data in the first cell is a number shown as time, while the second is just a text. If you type `1234:12` Excel interprets it as a time, and converts it into a number. If you type `12345:12` Excel considers that a text, so you need to convert it to a number in the expression. Perhaps you could avoid the formulas by changing the way you input the data. How do you get to this point?

Comment: This data is emailed to me, so it came to me this way. Could you explain " If you type 1234:12 Excel interprets it as a time, and converts it into a number. If you type 12345:12 Excel considers that a text, so you need to convert it to a number in the expression. " again?

Comment: I edited the question to explain it, because it would be too long for a comment.